# How set request.referer in Rails 5 (ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5, default testing engine (ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest)

How can I set the content of **request.referer** in test environment.

It work perfectly on dev environment but it is **nil** when I run tests.

Answer (score 2):

I found a reply in the docs (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#setting-headers-and-cgi-variables)

You can set **request.referer** using the following syntax :

```
get articles_url, headers: { "HTTP_REFERER": "http://example.com/home" }
```

In this case **request.referer** will be equal to http://example.com/home

Answer (score 0):

**For RSPEC 3, RAILS 5**

```
let(:headers) { some: "header" }
#...
request.headers.merge! headers
post :endpoint, params: params
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1655#issuecomment-250418438